# RegEx for matching a string except specific words

Tags: regex, excel, vba, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

In Excel VBA, I'm trying to use regex method to match a string. Once the match occurs, I want the matched string to include the entire string unless there is a keyword that happens after the end of the match string.  Illustrated differently, the regex pattern is as follows:

```
pattern = (CHECKOUT[a-zA-Z_(/ ):]+\w+:\w+\s((AM|PM)|(am|pm))\s\-\s\w+:\w+\s((AM|PM)|(am|pm)))
```

the strings that are input are:

```
1. CHECKOUT Senior Guest Services Manager FRONTENDMGR: 07:00 AM - 08:30 AM SGSM_BOOKKEEPING: 08:30 AM - 01:00 PM FRONTENDMGR: 01:00 PM - 04:00 PM

2. CHECKOUT Guest Services Manager BOOKKEEPER: 09:00 AM - 01:00 PM DRY GOODS Receiving Clerk RECEIVE: 04:30 AM - 09:00 AM 

3. DRY GOODS Receiving Clerk RECEIVE: 04:30 AM - 09:00 AM CHECKOUT Guest Services Manager BOOKKEEPER: 09:00 AM - 01:00 PM
```

with the first string, I want the entire string returned but only the following is returned:
CHECKOUT Senior Guest Services Manager FRONTENDMGR: 07:00 AM - 08:30 AM

with the second string, I want only the first part of the string from "CHECKOUT" TO "01:00 PM" returned and that works well.

with the third string, i only want the part between "CHECKOUT" TO "01:00 PM" returned and that occurs.

So the only one that doesn't occur is the first string, where I want the entire string returned but only the first part matches.

So I need to adjust the pattern to include everything unless the word "DRY GOODS" is in the string and if so, only return the portion between the words "CHECKOUT" AND "AM" OR "PM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you show, and what you describe, I think this might do it:

```
\bCHECKOUT.*?(?=\s*DRY GOODS|$)
```

That will return, from you data:

```
CHECKOUT Senior Guest Services Manager FRONTENDMGR: 07:00 AM - 08:30 AM SGSM_BOOKKEEPING: 08:30 AM - 01:00 PM FRONTENDMGR: 01:00 PM - 04:00 PM
CHECKOUT Guest Services Manager BOOKKEEPER: 09:00 AM - 01:00 PM
CHECKOUT Guest Services Manager BOOKKEEPER: 09:00 AM - 01:00 PM
```

We match `CHECKOUT` and then everything else up to (but not including) `DRY GOODS`.  And if we don't find `DRY GOODS`, we continue to the end of the string.

If the string extends over multiple lines, may need to replace `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`

If your data is such that you absolutely must match the `AM|PM` at the end, then try:

```
\bCHECKOUT.*(?:AM|PM)(?=.*?DRY GOODS|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might update your pattern to use a negative lookahead `(?!` after the match to assert what is on the right does not contain `DRY GOOD`

```
\bCHECKOUT[a-zA-Z_(/ ):]+\w+:\w+\s(?:[AP]M|[ap]m)\s-\s\w+:\w+\s(?:[AP]M|[ap]m)(?!.*\bDRY GOODS\b).*
```

**Explanation**

- `\bCHECKOUT` Match literally with a word boundary to prevent the word being part of a larger word
- `[a-zA-Z_(/ ):]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `\w+:\w+\s` Match 1+ word chars, then `:` and again 1+ word chars followed by whitespace char
- `(?:[AP]M|[ap]m)` Match either AM PM am pm
- `\s-\s\w+:\w+\s` Match a series of whitespace char, `-`, `:` and word char
- `(?:[AP]M|[ap]m)` Match either AM PM am pm
- `(?!.*\bDRY GOODS\b)` Assert what is on the right does not contain DRY GOODS between word boundaries
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtkBVS/1)